# Ask access_level from database

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have code, which should use access levels, but from the database my code is not requesting the access level and I do not get into my "admin.php"

Can you help?

Login page is here:
[Login-Page](http://www.frijk.net/1/)

Credentials: test / test

I want to let users login into my page, which is access for recruiters of me. So I can create users, they see my CV and others. Therefor it is neccessary to set user levels like "1" for admin.php "2" for admin2.php and so on.

Here's the check.php which is a form from the index.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once("inc/config.inc.php");
require_once("inc/functions.inc.php");

$error_msg = "";
if(isset($_POST['uname']) && isset($_POST['pwd'])) {
$email = $_POST['uname'];
$passwort = $_POST['pwd'];

$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :uname");
$result = $statement->execute(array('uname' => $email));
$user = $statement->fetch();

//Überprüfung des Passworts
if ($user !== false && password_verify($passwort, $user['pwd'])) {
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $user['id'];
    $access_level = $user['access_level'];
    $_SESSION['access_level'] = $access_level;

    //Möchte der Nutzer angemeldet beleiben?
    if(isset($_POST['angemeldet_bleiben'])) {
        $identifier = random_string();
        $securitytoken = random_string();

        $insert = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO securitytokens (user_id, access_level, identifier, securitytoken) VALUES (:user_id, :access_level, :identifier, :securitytoken)");
        $insert->execute(array('user_id' => $user['id'], 'access_level' => $access_level, 'identifier' => $identifier, 'securitytoken' => sha1($securitytoken)));
        setcookie("identifier",$identifier,time()+(3600*24*365)); //Valid for 1 year
        setcookie("securitytoken",$securitytoken,time()+(3600*24*365)); //Valid for 1 year
    }
    if ($access_level==0){
        header("Location:user.php");
        }
    else if($access_level==1){
        header("Location:admin.php");
        }
    }
else{
    header("Location:index.php?err=1");
    }

} else {
    $error_msg =  "E-Mail oder Passwort war ungültig<br><br>";
}


$email_value = "";
if(isset($_POST['email']))
$email_value = htmlentities($_POST['email']); 
?>
```

The problem was here in line

```
<?php 
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :uname");
```

there's no table named "email" - so it's not possible to get a true request.

I changed it to:

```
<?php 
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname = :uname");
```

After that, my page gives me the output:

Hello This is admin page.

Thanks at all of you for your help! :)

Comment: I found the solution - see edited.

Answer (score 0):

May be your mistake is here.
`$access_level = ['access_level'];`.

it should be like 
`$access_level = $user['access_level'];`.

and I don't get your situation. 
other mistake is may be here.

```
if(isset($_POST['angemeldet_bleiben'])) {
        $identifier = random_string();
        $securitytoken = random_string(); //remaining code....
    }
    else if ($access_level==0){
        header("Location:user.php");
        }
    else if($access_level==1){
        header("Location:admin.php");
        }
```

don't you think it should be like.

```
if ($access_level==0){ //removed else.
        header("Location:user.php");
        }
    else if($access_level==1){
        header("Location:admin.php");
        }
```

because if first `if` condition worked then it skips all other `else if` statements.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It's still not working. 
Maybe there's another mistake in my check.php?

Comment: @ManuelFrick can you share table columns or table screenshoot?

Comment: @ManuelFrick Please can you make sure all details are added to your question, not as links in comments (there should be an "edit" link under the question). This site has a slightly different format to a normal discussion forum; you might want to take the [tour] if you haven't already.

Comment: Thank you very much for your edits. The situation is following:

I want to let users login into my page, which is access for recruiters of me. So i can create users, they see my CV and others. Therefor it is neccessary to set user levels like "1" for admin.php "2" for admin2.php and so on.

Comment: @ManuelFrick thanks for explaining. my answer worked this?

Comment: @ManuelFrick okay. did you check var `$access_level` value. may be `$access_level` value is not the expected value. or may be the it is casting issue as you are using `access_level` as `varchar` datatype in table.

Comment: @MahmoodSanjrani: Thanks for your help - found the problem - see in my edited question above.

Comment: @ManuelFrick ohh.. this was the error.. Happy to know you solved it by yourself. :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check `print_r($user)`? What is returned? What datatype has your column "access_level" in your database?
Maybe you have to check `$access_level=='0'`, if it is type string.

Comment: Thanks for your help - found the problem - see in my edited question above.